# Minute's vs Minutes

Tags: apostrophe

Referring to a newborne: "her first minute's took place a few hours ago" or "her first minutes took place a few hours ago."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. On matters of punctuation, you should adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: That said, the apostrophe is essentially never used for pluralization in standard written English, though it appears commonly enough in plurals that such use has a nickname, the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-greengrocers-apostrophe-1690826). In conventional usage, the apostrophe indicates a possessive, a contraction, or an abbreviation; it may therefore be acceptable here if that is the context.

Comment: Spelling: newborn, or new-born. No 'e' at the end.

Answer (score 3):

No apostrophe. The apostrophe makes the noun possessive; without it, it's plural (which is what you want).